# TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'value')

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm getting an error that is :

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'value')`

the code is as follow:

```
this.setState({ initialResponse: initialResponse.data });
  const stateObj = { ...this.props.airlineAdminEditResponse };
  Object.keys(stateObj).map(sectionKey => {
    let sectionStateObj = stateObj[sectionKey];
    if (this.state.initialResponse["selectedFieldInfos"][sectionKey]) {
      let sectionObj = this.state.initialResponse["selectedFieldInfos"][sectionKey];
      Object.keys(sectionObj).map(fieldKey => {
        if (sectionObj[fieldKey]) {
          let fieldStateObj = sectionStateObj[fieldKey];
          let fieldObj = sectionObj[fieldKey];
          stateObj[sectionKey][fieldKey]["value"] = fieldObj;
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

Comment: Hey Zaid! I'm not sure I understand your error message. What property does it say you tried to set on undefined? you wrote in brackets that it's `value`, but there is no `.value = ...` line in your code

Comment: Your stateObj[sectionKey] is undefined, by consequence you cannot define a field ["value"] on it

Comment: yea im getting stateObj[sectionKey] as undefined let me see why is that happening and i will update